# How to set permissions on S3 Bucket while creating it through GoLang API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I am creating an S3 Bucket for AWS Billing reports. I want to set GrantRead, GrantWrite and GrandReadACP permissions on S3 Bucket while creating it through GoLang API. Which value do I need to pass to these tags to set these three permissions for authenticated AWS users?

Answer (score 0):

you can review the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/S3.html#CreateBucket-instance_method) for the `CreateBucket` method which takes policy arguments you mention

```
    // set your s3 client before and define your bucket as bucketName

    params := &s3.CreateBucketInput{
             Bucket: aws.String(bucketName),

             GrantRead:        aws.String("GrantRead"),
             GrantReadACP:     aws.String("GrantReadACP"),
             GrantWrite:       aws.String("GrantWrite"),
             // GrantFullControl and others available
     }

     result, err := s3client.CreateBucket(params)
```

as [the issue points out](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/issues/491) it might not work so using the ACL directly as something like

```
    // set your s3 client before and define your bucket as bucketName

    params := &s3.CreateBucketInput{
             Bucket: aws.String(bucketName),

             ACL: aws.String("public-read | public-read-write")
     }

     result, err := s3client.CreateBucket(params)
```

see [canned ACL doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#canned-acl) for possible values

Comment: have you tried creating the bucket using the parameters that you have mentioned above? I think these are not the actual values of these tags, these are just sample values. The API is throwing "invalid argument format" exception when using these values.

Comment: right, I point to the doc and thought it would work (as you did not indicate yourself you've been trying it) - seems other struggle with that https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/issues/491 and propose to use ACL policies directly

Comment: Thank you. I already tried with ACL, it's working fine. But my requirement isn't being fulfilled by ACL and I need ACP Permissions.
I appreciate that you spare time to answer the Question.